# Split a string in Python and extract few fields from list

Tags: python, split

I recently started working with Python and I am trying to split a string in Python and then extract only fields from that list.

Below is my node string and it will always be of four words separated by `/`.

```
node = "/tt/pf/test/v1"
```

I am trying to split above string on `/` and then store `test` and `v1` value from it in some variable -

Below is what I have tried -

```
node = "/tt/pf/test/v1"
a,b,c,d = node.split("/")
print c
print d
```

Below is the error I got -

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Beauty of Python is: if you don't know if it works or wonder how it does it just type this `"/tt/pf/test/v1".split("/")` into console and see what comes out ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not taking into the account the empty string generated by the first / character:

```
node = "/tt/pf/test/v1"
node.split('/')
['', 'tt', 'pf', 'test', 'v1']
```

A quick fix can be this:

```
_,a,b,c,d = node.split("/")
```

or slice the `split()` result:

```
a,b,c,d = node.split("/")[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

This divides it into 5 values, not 4, because it includes the empty string before the `/` at the start.

```
node.split("/")
# ['', 'tt', 'pf', 'test', 'v1']
```

Try:

```
empty,a,b,c,d = node.split("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

> node.split("/")

['', 'tt', 'pf', 'test', 'v1']

First one counts as an empty word.
Try: skip,a,b,c,d = node.split("/")

Comment: Your answer is correct, try to format it to make it more appealing and understandable :)